# Rendering rotated text in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I am trying to generate rotated text in one line and center of the div. Why does the text inside the `#map` appear in 3 lines?

[image]

but I want to have something like:

[image]

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");
#map{
  display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    color: #ed217c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1"><span id="map">Here is Starter Plan</span></div>
  <div class="col-xs-11" style="background:red;min-height:400px;">Rest Of Content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `translate` to get it properly positioned and use `white-space: nowrap;` to have no line breakes.

```css
#map {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, -30px);
  color: #ed217c;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```